# Source not found for the file Activity.class

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

I have a problem with creating more than one activity in an Android project. The problem occurs only when i'm debugging. It's not a runtime error. I don't have any clue why i still keep getting this error. I already did a lot of research but now I'm a bit desperate because solutions on the web didn't solve the problem.

The error more detailed:

Source not found
Source not found for the file Activity.class error
The source attachment does not contain the source for the file Activity.class

[Button] Change Attached Source

When i click on that button i see the path to the android.jar file:
C:/Program Files/android/platforms/android-19/android.jar

[SOLVED]
This is an good tutorial how to solve this problem.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IdIZ7r2d4J4

Comment: The problem is your ADT/SDK set up and not the way you have programmed your classes then.You are extending a class(Activity class) that the SDK cannot find its source defination.

Comment: check your package name.because in Activity you have written like com.example.turfwars but in  package="com.example.turfwarsv1" so just check it

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code i notice a few anomalies.Please use

```
protected void onCreate()
```

and not `public void onCreate()`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Java for Android but it looks like your code is trying to use the same UI space for two fullscreen windows.

Answer (score 0):

May be it is something with casing?

Can you be more specific about your problem.
1) Is it a compile error or runtime?
2) What message you got in either case?

Original doc: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Simple code for starting second activity by button with id = button

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
   b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
           startActivity(i);
       }
    });
}
```